# Setting CALayer transform property causes a crash

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I am building an interactive rotating disc control. When the user drags the view, I apply the rotation transform for the view. Like this:

```
circleView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1)
```

For some reason, this line of code causes the app to crash. The crash is not happening on the first hit of this line, but after a 
few seconds of consecutive rotation. If I comment this line out, the crash is not occurring.

To make things worse, when the app crashes xcode doesn't show any error or stacktrace but says "connection to device is lost".

This happening only on a device. On the simulator all goes fine.

In the crash logs of the device, at the time of the crash I see no crashes of my apps but there is a crash of processes DTServiceHub

```
Incident Identifier: 02336F7A-CAB3-4B13-9509-65EA61813529
CrashReporter Key:   e16756d8ab2514bab0584705f4151434dbed594f
Hardware Model:      iPad3,4
Process:             DTServiceHub [768]
Path:                /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/DTServiceHub
Identifier:          DTServiceHub
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           <none> [352]


Date/Time:           2018-10-02 18:26:03.0352 +0300
Launch Time:         2018-10-02 18:25:45.0000 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0bd5f30c
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]


hread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: NStatManager queue
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1d404dc6 objc_msgSend + 6
1   CoreFoundation                  0x1e086210 -[__NSDictionaryM objectForKey:] + 128
2   IDEDebugGaugeDataProviders      0x00439278 0x430000 + 37496
3   IDEDebugGaugeDataProviders      0x004382a8 0x430000 + 33448
4   NetworkStatistics               0x240ab374 -[NWStatisticsDelegateBlockWrapper sourceDidReceiveCounts:] + 160
5   NetworkStatistics               0x240a548c __59-[NWStatisticsManager dispatchDidReceiveCounts:fromUpdate:]_block_invoke + 110
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d83d796 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d84a59c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d840b70 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d84c1b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d84c00e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1d9f287c _pthread_wqthread + 1040
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1d9f245c start_wqthread + 8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is circle view released at any point? Put a log above this line to check. Any memory constraints going on at the time? Are you directly setting the transform or is this part of an animation?

Comment: No, it is not released. It is stored with a strong reference in the parent view. I am setting the transform directly from the UI thread. What do you mean by memory constraints?

Comment: are you using lots of images.  I wondered if you are getting a memory crash.  Also the crash shows a NSDictionary.  Any use of objectFor key from you

Comment: Fixed it! The problem was that the setting the transform property of the child view was triggering layoutSubviews method of the parent view.  And in that layoutSubviews method I am programmatically drawing some images. So maybe those images somehow were causing a memory issue when created many times... So I just wrapped the transforming view in additional container view and it solved the problem.

Comment: Yep! Good catch. Any adjustment to `frame` will implicitly call `layoutSubviews` on that view. Since `frame` is composed of `center` (`position` in Core Animation, technically), `bounds`, and `transform` (plus `anchorPoint` in Core Animation), any changes to those properties can trigger a layout pass.